# Are there any significant differences between Edge of the Empire and Age of Rebellion?

Tags: edition-comparison, star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion

As far as I can tell, both titles are recent and from Fantasy Flight Games — are there any differences between the two in terms of mechanics, tone, etc.?

Comment: Is your question actually wondering what the *point* of these two different games existing is? The answer to that is different than what answers this question as-written will likely get.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie- I'm asking how they differ from each other (if at all).

Comment: And I'm asking for the deeper reason why you're even asking, since a useful answer requires knowing that. Are you looking at both and trying to decide which to buy? Are you wondering if they're compatible? Are you wondering if one is more up-to-date than the other? Are you wondering if one is the replacement for the other? Something else? What **problem** are you wanting us to solve?

Comment: This is a common question from those with little to no access to the core books. Online descriptions from the company are unclear on this point and many wonder if they need all three games, a combination, only one, if the rules have changed during the run, etc. The question is easily answered in its current (edited by SevenSidedDie) form, solving the problem of "I am not sure if this is 1 game or 3."

Comment: @Runeslinger this is a fragment of a question not, a full question as-is. Your version of it is a valid question but it is inferred vs. the very broad single sentence question asked above and so once the OP expands it to include purpose we can probably reopen.

Comment: @kingofpanes if you're asking *how* they're different, you need to [edit] your question to ask that. Right now, the question is "*are there any differences?*" Not "***what** are the differences"?* The answer to your comment-question is a good question; the answer to your current question is a simple 'yes, there are differences.'